# What type of cable is this?

Tags: electrical, cables

What type of cable is this? I found it in the wall without any junction box just taped off at the end with electrical tape.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: look at the printing on the cable ... probably cat5 cable ... probably for ethernet or for telephone

Comment: Can you provide us with a close-up of the printing on the cable jacket, or post the text for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a data cable.

Probably CAT5 or CAT5E grade. (it will be written on the blue jacket every metre.)

These cables are used for ethernet (between computers and routers) and for connecting telephones, and home automation equipment, intercoms, thermostats etc. I'm guessing there used to be a phone jack there.

Comment: 4 wires out of 8? Phone, +1